# "Access to this resource has been denied" for Business Components endpoint in HP ALM Rest API

Tags: java, rest, hp-alm

Trying to create custom script using HP ALM Rest API and while all endpoints are working fine \bp-components endpoint gives me following:

Response code: 403
{"Id":"qccore.operation-forbidden","Title":"Access to this resource has been denied","ExceptionProperties":null,"StackTrace":null}

Does anyone were able to access BPT resources via rest api?
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.